# Return confidence score with custom model for Vertex AI batch predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I uploaded a pretrained scikit learn classification model to Vertex AI and ran a batch prediction on 5 samples. It just returned a list of false predictions with no confidence score. I don't see anywhere in the SDK documentation or GCP console how to get batch predictions to include the confidence scores. Is that something Vertex AI can do?

My intent is to automate a batch prediction pipeline using the following code.

```
batch_prediction_job = model.batch_predict(
    job_display_name = job_display_name,
    gcs_source = input_path,
    instances_format = "", # "jsonl", "csv", "bigquery", 
    gcs_destination_prefix = output_path,
    starting_replica_count = 1,
    max_replica_count = 10,
    sync = True,
)

batch_prediction_job.wait()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do this with the [custom prediction routines](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines). Here are a couple good e2e examples

- [Official google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/community/ml_ops/stage6/get_started_with_cpr.ipynb)
- [One of mine](https://github.com/jswortz/GCP-Vertex-Stuff/blob/main/3.pands-sklearn-custom-container.ipynb) - focuses on batch prediction with `predict_proba()`

Here's an example of the interface for the predictor.py:

```
%%writefile src/predictor.py
import joblib
import numpy as np
import pickle

from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.aiplatform.prediction.sklearn.predictor import SklearnPredictor
import json

class CprPredictor(SklearnPredictor):
    
    def __init__(self):
        return
    
    def load(self, gcs_artifacts_uri: str):
        """Loads the preprocessor artifacts."""
        gcs_client = storage.Client()
        with open("model.joblib", 'wb') as gcs_model:
            gcs_client.download_blob_to_file(
                gcs_artifacts_uri + "/model.joblib", gcs_model
            )

        with open("model.joblib", "rb") as f:
            self._model = joblib.load("model.joblib")

    
    def predict(self, instances):
        outputs = self._model.predict_proba(instances) 
        return outputs
```

Note you have to utilize an experimental branch of the SDK at the moment, will likely change to official.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so; the stock sklearn container provided by vertex doesn't provide such a score I guess. You might need to write a [custom container](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/use-custom-container).

Answer (score 1):

You have to build your own docker container to make BatchPrediction return probabilities.

In order to make it work, you have to write some files (serving application) and build them inside a docker container which will be used as the serving container for your model. This procedure assumes you to have a fitted sklearn model (named as `model.pkl`) saved in a bucket (`gs://MYPROJECT/MYFOLDERS/model.pkl`)

The desired structure of your serving application is as follows:

```
serving_src
|__ Dockerfile
|__ requirements.txt
|__ app
    |__ main.py
    |__ prestart.sh
```

The `main.py` file contains the code to serve predictions using `FastAPI`:

```
# Import the required libraries
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import pickle
import json
import os
from google.cloud import storage
import logging

app = FastAPI()
# Define the Cloud Storage client
gcs_client = storage.Client()

# Download the model file from Cloud Storage bucket
with open("model.pkl", 'wb') as model_f:
    gcs_client.download_blob_to_file(
            f"{os.environ['AIP_STORAGE_URI']}/model.pkl", model_f
        )
    
# Load the scikit-learn model/pipeline file
_model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb')) 

# Define a function for health route
@app.get(os.environ['AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE'], status_code=200)
def health():
    return {}

# Define a function for prediction route
@app.post(os.environ['AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE'])
async def predict(request: Request):
    # await the request
    body = await request.json()
    # parse the request instances
    instances = body["instances"]
    # pass it to the model/pipeline for prediction scores
    predictions = _model.predict_proba(instances).tolist()
    # return the batch prediction scores
    return {"predictions": predictions}
```

The `requirements.txt` file specifies the package versions for the serving application:

```
numpy==1.23.3
scikit-learn==1.0
google-cloud-storage>=1.44.0,<2.0.0dev
```

The `prestart.sh` bash script sets the port to `AIP_HTTP_PORT` (we use 8080). The container's HTTP server listens for requests on this port:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PORT=8080
```

The `Dockerfile` for containerizing the serving application using gunicorn:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9

COPY ./app /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When all the files are ready, move outside the `serving_src` and run the following commands to build your container and push it on your project artifact registry:

```
docker build --no-cache -t europe-docker.pkg.dev/MYPROJECT/MYREPONAME/sklearn-custom-serving:latest serving_src
docker push europe-docker.pkg.dev/MYPROJECT/MYREPONAME/sklearn-custom-serving:latest
```

It's recommended to test the container before use it:

```
docker run -it -p 80:8080 \
    --name=my-fancy-serving-app \
    -e AIP_HTTP_PORT=8080 \
    -e AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE=/health \
    -e AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE=/predict \
    -e AIP_STORAGE_URI=gs://MYPROJECT/MYFOLDERS \
    europe-docker.pkg.dev/MYPROJECT/MYREPONAME/sklearn-custom-serving:latest
```

If the run is fine, you are ready to use your container to make BatchPrediction generating probabilities.

The serving container can be specified:

- as `model_serving_container_image_uri` when starting a `CustomTrainingJob`
- as `serving_container_image_uri` when uploading a trained model to Model Registry with `google.cloud.aiplatform.Model.upload`
- setting `container_spec` in `unmanaged_container_model` when calling  `google.cloud.aiplatform.gapic.JobServiceClient.create_batch_prediction_job`